# Add gravity to EditText programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, gravity

I try add CENTER_VERTICAL to EditText:

```
((EditText)childView).setGravity( ((EditText)childView).getGravity() | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

I need ADD (but NOT CHANGE !!!) any another current gravity of View.

Example, EditText already have gravity LEFT. I try

```
((EditText)childView).setGravity( Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

but new gravity is kill LEFT gravity.

What is best way to ADD new gravity?

Comment: you can't add gravity instead you can set just one

Comment: which layout are you using for the EditText?

Comment: I use parent TableLayout. I try code (see below), but no result

Comment: Can we have you Code snippet here? for better understand.

Answer (score 10):

**Try:**

```
((EditText)childView).setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

You must be knowing the initial gravity set.

Answer (score 0):

You can try gravity by setting it in params

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

((EditText)childView).setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I try this. 'TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams( TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); layoutParams.gravity = layoutParams.gravity | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL; ((EditText)childView).setLayoutParams( layoutParams); '. But this code destroy previous gravity of view.

Answer (score 0):

When you creating EditText programmatically, you must at first set setKeyListener(TextKeyListener.getInstance());

Otherwise your view will always be aligned with Gravity.TOP.

I don't know real reason, but before you specifiy any other parameter to EditText, you must set setKeyListener(TextKeyListener.getInstance());

**Correction : It only work if you create you custom widget by extending  EditText and defining your widget in XML. Only tested on Android 5.0.1**